# Java gui как разделить два JList

Tags: java, gui, swing

Получается пока что так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Как разъединить два листа (чтобы между ними было расстояние, пробовал border, separator это не то)
2. Как сделать JTextField по меньше?

```html
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JPanel panel_1;
    private JButton btnNewButton;
    private JButton btnNewButton_1;
    private JPanel panel_2;
    private JPanel panel_3;
    private JPanel panel_4;
    private JPanel panel_5;
    private JButton btnDelete;
    private JButton btnNewButton_3;
    private JList list;
    private JList list_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test frame = new test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 400, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0, 0, 0));

        textField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel.add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        btnNewButton = new JButton("Add");
        btnNewButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 23));
        panel_1.add(btnNewButton);

        btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Run");
        btnNewButton_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 23));
        panel_1.add(btnNewButton_1);

        panel_2 = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout flowLayout_1 = (FlowLayout) panel_2.getLayout();
        flowLayout_1.setHgap(20);
        contentPane.add(panel_2, BorderLayout.WEST);

        panel_3 = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panel_3.getLayout();
        flowLayout.setHgap(20);
        contentPane.add(panel_3, BorderLayout.EAST);

        panel_4 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel_4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 3));
        
        list = new JList();
        list.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel_4.add(list);
        
        list_1 = new JList();
        list_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel_4.add(list_1);

        panel_5 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_5, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        btnDelete.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 23));
        panel_5.add(btnDelete);

        btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("Clear");
        btnNewButton_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 23));
        panel_5.add(btnNewButton_3);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вы используете грид менеджер, то следует указывать кол-во "колонок". Посмотрите какие параметры этот менеджер принимает в конструктор, и всё сразу станет ясно. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

```
            // Your code
            panel_4 = new JPanel();
            contentPane.add(panel_4);                        // delete lay here
            panel_4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 10)); // set 2 Columns and gap
    
            list = new JList();
            list.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            panel_4.add(list);
            
            list_1 = new JList();
            list_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            panel_4.add(list_1);
            // Your code
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но теперь листы смещены относительно кнопок, можно это исправить?

Comment: Ясно, нужно было gap уменьшить, спасибо.

Comment: Не понял, чтобы всё равно было ? изменить hgap и vgap на 5(вместо 10)

Comment: Да, разобрался, спасибо.

Comment: а как уменьшить высоту textField?

Comment: @Shadow_fiend Если речь идёт о адаптивном макете, то скорее всего придётся разделить панель + лэйаут кнопок и текст филда. Поскольку высота одного Diminsion влияет и на всех остальных, попробуйте повысить значение высоты у кнопок до 50. Текст филд тоже сыграет в высоту